# Structuring an HTML document for Safari Reader

Tags: html, safari, structure

I'm having a bit of trouble structuring an HTML document for Safari Reader. Specifically, Reader is bringing my H2 tag above my H1 and I can't figure out why.

The structure of the document is basically this:

```
<h1>
<p>
<p>
<h2>
<h3>...
```

And here it is in action: http://www.dontwakemeup.com/2013/who.html

There's still lots of cleaning up to do, but I thought that getting it to work in Reader would be relatively straightforward and this one is really bugging me. Any ideas?

Comment: is this the actual code, or like you say the structure?

Comment: No this is just the abbreviated structure to illustrate that my h1 tag is before my h2 tag, yet it appears after it in Reader. You can see the actual code at the link there.